# Read file from S3 into a buffer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a function in Lambda that requires a file from S3 to be read into a buffer. I have seen multiple examples of them being read into streams but none with buffers. My current code for getting the object is

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    //console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));
    const srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const srcKey    = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));

    const params = 
        {
            Bucket: srcBucket,
            Key: srcKey
        };

    try 
    {
        var slippiGame = s3.getObject(params, function(error, data) 
        {
            if (error)
            {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else
            {
                const game = new SlippiGame(slippiGame);
            }
        });
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
        console.log("fail");
        console.log(e);
    }

    console.log(slippiGame);

    return("success");
};
```

I know that this approach is wrong since my slippiGame variable isn't a buffer and the SlippiGame constructor only takes a local file or a buffer. Is there a way to either store the file from S3 temporarily in the Lambda directory or create a buffer to hold the S3 file in?

Answer (score 4):

The `Body` attribute of `data` is already a Buffer.

If you prefer file download, create a read stream from the response and pipe it to a write stream. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/requests-using-stream-objects.html) for more.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
const params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myImageFile.jpg'};
const file = require('fs').createWriteStream('/path/to/file.jpg');
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file);
```

One additional problem with your current code: you are mixing the async and the callback variants of the Lambda function handler -- it's better to just use the async variant and get rid of `callback`

Comment: I've changed it such that it is async but the code inside of my getObject function is not executing. Do I have to wrap the entire thing in a promise? I'm trying to execute a function on the buffer retrieved from S3.

Comment: I'm not sure what your new code looks like but all AWS SDK functions have promisified variants, for example: `const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise()`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am getting the right data now but I think there is some sort of an issue with async that I'm not familiar with. My current code is https://pastebin.com/JgYFFDvU and my output changes every time that I test it in Lambda, with the resulting output sometimes being https://pastebin.com/Pda5d9qP. Is there a stack where the data is being pushed that I have to empty? Or am I doing something wrong with the async function?

Comment: You can’t both await the result of the getObject() call and use a callback. Just remove the callback completely and use the await example I provided in my earlier comment.